# Controller not receiving object id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to pass the category.id to the shop/index controller using

```
<% Category.all.each do |category| %>
        <div><%= link_to category.name.titleize, shop_index_path :category_id => category.id  %></div>
        <hr>
    <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class ShopController < ApplicationController    
    def index
        @products = Category.find(params[:category_id]).products
    end    
end
```

Where a category has many products. But Whenever I click the link I get

```
Couldn't find Category without an ID
```

Can anyone see why this is?

EDIT: This is the route I use

```
get 'shop/index'
```

Comment: try add params `shop_index_path(params: { :category_id => category.id })`

Answer (score 4):

try add `params`:

```
shop_index_path(params: { category_id: category.id })
```

You need refine you routes for passing `params`:

```
get 'shop/index/:category_id', to: 'shop#index'
```

And now you can pass `category_id` to path helper like:

```
shop_index_path(category.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<%= link_to category.name.titleize, shop_index_path(category.id) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you could just use:

```
shop_index_path(category.id)
```

And then load:

```
Category.find(params[:id]).products
```

Comment: This likely won't work after seeing RSB's answer - can you post your routes?

Comment: Thanks for reply - can you post your routes

Comment: Nice but I still want to see your routes - what you're doing isn't conventional

Comment: Ah i see, adding the route i use now